# Generate incremental values by rows with timestamp in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if there's a way I can generate rows of incremental values with timestamp rolling at the same time. At the moment, I am thinking to do it manually by increasing the values and timestampe in a separate dataframes and trying to join them together. Any better solution?

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

data = {
    'apple': {Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): 10},
    'orange': {Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): 20},
    'lemon': {Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00'): 30}
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
            apple  orange  lemon
2020-01-01     10      20     30
```

Expected output:

```
                apple              orange               lemon
date
2021-01-01          10                 20                  30
2022-01-01          20                 30                  40
2023-01-01          30                 40                  50
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
#reepat index values
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)]

#counter by duplicated index values
s = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount()
#multiple counter by 10 and add to all columns
df = df.add(s.mul(10), axis=0)
#if always January 1 add years by counter Series
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.year + s + 1, format='%Y')
print (df)
            apple  orange  lemon
2021-01-01     10      20     30
2022-01-01     20      30     40
2023-01-01     30      40     50
```

Comment: This is almost what I need and I am wondering if the multiplication can be done on previous row value instead. In this case, the 2nd row becomes `200, 300, 400` and the 3rd row becomes `2000, 3000, 4000`.

Comment: @codedancer - do you think `df = df.add(s.mul(10), axis=0).mul(10**s, axis=0)` instead `df = df.add(s.mul(10), axis=0)` ? multiple by 1, 10, 100? But last row is `2023-01-01   3000    4000   5000`

Answer (score 0):

You can try convert each element in dataframe to list then explode

```py
n = 3

df = (df.applymap(lambda x: range(x, x+10*n, 10))
      .reset_index())
df['index'] =df['index'].apply(lambda d: pd.date_range(d, freq='YS', periods=n))
df = (df.explode(df.columns.tolist())
      .set_index('index'))
```

```
print(df)

           apple orange lemon
index
2020-01-01    10     20    30
2021-01-01    20     30    40
2022-01-01    30     40    50
```